# May we please apply the same URL-to-Question-Title feature into the comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

One of my favorite auto-complete features is the one where you simply post the URL of a Stack Question into the question box, and it automagically turns it into the title(that is - upon clicking "Save Edits" ).

Would there be a way to also do this for the comment box? I just think it would be a nifty feature, and enhance the overall flow of things.

Comment: Sounds like a good suggestion to me

Comment: From MSE: [Replace links with the current question title in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments) which is status-declined (though from 2011 - though the technical reasoning for the status-declined is probably still in the design of the site now).  See also the [linked questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/77394?lq=1).

Comment: [SE Comment Link Helper](http://stackapps.com/q/2378) - This userscript automatically converts raw Stack Exchange question URLs into the form [title](link) before submitting comments by grabbing their titles from the API. This is similar to conversion done natively on posts, ...

Comment: this is really a question for MSE, not MSO, right? (and seems to be a duplicate of what MichaelT linked)