# Is there a way I can view questions by new members or low quality questions?

Tags: discussion, new-users, quality-filter

I will love to offer help more but most of the questions I see in my homepage are always too advanced for me to help. I think I can assist in questions that are in the basic to intermediate level of many popular languages. But I find it difficult to filter that out. Is there a way that can be done?

Comment: There is no way to filter by skill level; that's pretty subjective.  You could search for questions that contain, "Basic", "Beginner", or, "Newbie", although the last should be edited out of questions.

Comment: @fbueckert:  *All* of that should be edited out of questions.  The level of skill of an asker as part of their problem statement is noise at best.

Comment: @Makoto Fair enough; I just thought the first two were more likely to be descriptors in the problem statement, ie. "I'm having a problem with this basic query", etc., etc.

Comment: Basic questions in my experience are 99.99999% of the time already asked and answered several times before. Please, do not answer just any question you see. Answer only questions that are not duplicate and follow the site rules. (to make your life even harder, sorry)

Comment: Actually, specialising in finding duplicates would be ***very*** helpful, both for the asker (especially if they are found quickly) and for those that can vote to close. You can just leave comments with the candidate duplicates (with proper links, link text being the title, not naked URLs - example: *[May we please apply the same URL-to-Question-Title feature into the comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280592)*, `[May we please apply the same URL-to-Question-Title feature into the comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280592)`).

Comment: For instance, I can't imagine *[How do I slice a string by characters in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55194935)* would ***not*** be a duplicate after 1,129,811 questions have been posted in [the Python tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) for more than 10 years (sorry for the double negative).